# cohomology ring of stable configuration spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, cohomology, configuration-spaces

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold without boundary. Distinct $k$-points $x_1,\cdots,x_k\in M$ are called stable if the potential energy given by coulomb forces among $k$ electrons reaches minimal locally at $(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$.    The $k$-th stable configuration space is defined by
$$
S(M,k)=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_k)\in M^k\mid x_1,\cdots,x_k \text{ are distinct and stable}. \}
$$

Let the $k$-th permutation group $\Sigma_k$ act on $S(M,k)$ by permuting coordinates. The $k$-th stable braid space is defined by
$$
S(M,k)/\Sigma_k.
$$

**Question:** Given $k\geq 2$ and $M$, what is the cohomology ring $H^*(S(M,k)/\Sigma_k)$? Some nontrivial examples & references are also wanted.

Comment: What is the mathematical formulation of being stable? Is it defined in the presence of some real valued function $M^{\times k}\to\mathbb{R}$ that you wish to study the loci of its local minimum?

Comment: Yes, Prof. It is given by coulomb force formula.

Comment: Can you please state this formula? I don't know what the formula is, and wonder how that will effect the computation of homology unless you can translate into some action of a group, or consider it as a map into some Lie algebra?! Otherwise, without the stability condition, the homology of the above configuration space, at least in some specific cases, is known.